# changing individual letter position with bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing

If I have a file called `text.txt`
and it contains one line of text, `ijbiaubiu`
is it possible to move each letter one space forward or back in the alphabet in order to encrypt it manually, with what I believe would be a ROT cipher?

How is it done?

I have tried `sed` and `perl -pi -e` but I don't know how to read the contents of the file before applying commands, and these utilities never did the trick.

To clarify, I am not looking for help encrypting my files.
Rather, with help learning how to use the CLI to shift about alphabetical characters in a file manually.

Comment: Over on [so]: [How to shift each letter of the string by a given number of letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441260/2072269)

Comment: This encryption is very easy to crack for a professional person. If you want good encryption, I suggest that you learn how to use GNU PG, `gpg`, which is part of an Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Don't roll your own encryption or use weak ciphers and encryption approaches like ROT.  Any standard computer can break a rot cipher quickly.  You need to learn how to use **proper secure methods** such as GnuPG for PGP encryption or such, rather than trying to roll your own ciphers.

Comment: Fear not. Its only practical use was to apply to decrypting and making rot ciphers for what they were. Its a good place to start learning to code cipher breaking tools by hand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `sed`

can do that with [the transform command `y/…/…/`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-49), e.g. to replace “a” with “b” and so forth:

```
sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/'
```

or with capitals:

```
sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA/'
```

To simplify this you can use `bash` Parameter expansion, to be exact [substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion):

```
a=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
b=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
r=1
sed "y/$a$b/${a:$r}${a::$r}${b:$r}${b::$r}/"
```

To alter the rotation just set `r` to the desired rotation, e.g. `r=13` for ROT13. It works with negative numbers as well. The same approach can be used for the below `perl` version.

To read from a file I recommend redirection ([here’s why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819)), e.g. `<text.txt sed …`, see below for an example. You can however also give the file as an argument to `sed`, e.g. `sed '…' text.txt`.

#### Example run

```
$ <<<"ijbiaubiu" sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/'
jkcjbvcjv
$ <<<"ijbiaubiu" sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy/'
hiahztaht
$ echo "ijbiaubiu" >rot_file
$ <rot_file sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/'
jkcjbvcjv
```

---

### `perl`

has an easy-to-use transliterator tool called `tr`, e.g. to replace “a” with “b” and so forth:

```
perl -npe 'tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/'
```

`-n` is to iterate over filename arguments and `-p` to print lines afterwards, same as adding `;print` to the expression would do.

#### Example run

```
$ <<<"ijbiaubiu" perl -npe 'tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/'
jkcjbvcjv
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using `tr` command. A search for "ROT cypher Bash" leads me to [caesar-cipher.sh](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/030b8e91a8d9a407caa6).

- Note that the commands are case sensitive.

Caesar cipher encoding:

```
$ echo "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG" | tr '[A-Z]' '[X-ZA-W]'
QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD
```

Caesar cipher decoding:

```
$ echo "QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD" | tr '[X-ZA-W]' '[A-Z]'
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

It can also be adjusted to ROT13 instead:

```
$ echo "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG" | tr '[A-Z]' '[N-ZA-M]'
GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT

$ echo "GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT" | tr '[N-ZA-M]' '[A-Z]'
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

In your case it would be:

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[X-ZA-W]' < file
```

---

Also from [another source](https://www.chmag.in/articles/momsguide/decoding-rot-using-the-echo-and-tr-commands-in-your-linux-terminal/) to decode (reverse the order of patterns to encode):

```
ROT-3 = tr 'd-za-cD-ZA-C' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-4 = tr 'e-za-dE-ZA-D' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-5 = tr 'f-za-eF-ZA-E' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-6 = tr 'g-za-fG-ZA-F' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-7 = tr 'h-za-gH-ZA-G' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-8 = tr 'i-za-hI-ZA-H' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-9 = tr 'j-za-iJ-ZA-I' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-10 = tr 'k-za-jK-ZA-J' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-11 = tr 'l-za-kL-ZA-K' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-12 = tr 'm-za-lM-ZA-L' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-13 = tr 'n-za-mN-ZA-M' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-14 = tr 'o-za-nO-ZA-N' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-15 = tr 'p-za-oP-ZA-O' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-16 = tr 'q-za-pQ-ZA-P' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-17 = tr 'r-za-qR-ZA-Q' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-18 = tr 's-za-rS-ZA-R' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-19 = tr 't-za-sT-ZA-S' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-20 = tr 'u-za-tU-ZA-T' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-21 = tr 'v-za-uV-ZA-U' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-22 = tr 'w-za-vW-ZA-V' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-23 = tr 'x-za-wX-ZA-W' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-24 = tr 'y-za-xY-ZA-X' 'a-zA-Z'
ROT-25 = tr 'z-za-yZ-ZA-Y' 'a-zA-Z'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat text.txt 
ijbiaubiu
```

A 1-rotation with Python, after setting `ROT = 1`:

```
$ python -c "with open('text.txt') as f: ROT = 1; print(''.join([chr((ord(char)- ord('a') + ROT)%26+ord('a')) for char in f.read().strip()]))"
jkcjbvcjv
```

Or setting `ROT = -1`:

```
$ python -c "with open('text.txt') as f: ROT = -1; print(''.join([chr((ord(char)- ord('a') + ROT)%26+ord('a')) for char in f.read().strip()]))"
hiahztaht
```

What it's doing is:

1. reading letters in from the file,
2. getting their integer (or **ord**inal) values,
3. subtracting the ordinal value of lowercase `a` to get a number from 0 - 25,
4. adding the rotation value,
5. taking `% 26` so after `z` you wrap around to `a` if necessary,
6. adding the ordinal value of lowercase `a` back and
7. converting the ordinal value to a string value.

If you know Python, it might be easier to read if it's not a 1-liner:

```
ROT = 1

def rotate_char(char, rotate_amount):
    return chr((ord(char) - ord('a') + rotate_amount)%26 + ord('a'))

with open('text.txt') as f:
    line = f.read().strip()
    print(''.join([rotate_char(char, ROT) for char in line]))
```